# Getting Class Not registered 80041054 on class that is registered

Tags: c#, c++, com

I'm calling CoCreateInstance from unmanaged code onto a managed class that is registered (the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx} registry entry exists and the file is correctly loaded from another program.

The code is below:

```
    HRESULT hRC;
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    char* sUTProgID = "My.Utilities";

    CLSID UTClassID;
    hRC = CLSIDFromProgID(
        _CW(sUTProgID),             // Pointer to the ProgID
        &UTClassID );               // Pointer to the CLSID
    if ( S_OK != hRC )
    {
        DOTRACE((_T("    CLSIDFromProgID error 0x%X\n", hRC)));
    }
    IUnknown* pUnknown;
    hRC = CoCreateInstance(
    UTClassID,                  // Class identifier (CLSID) of the object
        0,                          // Pointer to whether object is or isn't part of an aggregate
        CLSCTX_ALL,                 // Context for running executable code
        IID_IUnknown,               // Reference to the identifier of the interface
        (void**) &pUnknown);        // Address of output variable that receives the interface pointer requested in riid
    if ( S_OK != hRC )
    {
    //code makes it here with an 80040145 class not registered error
    }
```

The same code works for the other application. The code is compiled for x86 and is running on an x86 machine.

EDIT: It's a windows XP machine so I assume UAC is out. I've logged the ClassID and it is indeed the correct one. I've also checked the ProcMon logs and it shows the registry key being accessed successfully and within the registry key the following paths are accessed:
InProcServer32 - success
InProcServerx86 - Name not found
LocalServer32 - Name not found 
InProcHandler32 - Name not found
AppId - Name not found
InProcServer32\ThreadingModel - success
InProcServer32\1.0.0.0 - success
InProcServer32\1.0.0.0\assembly - buffer overflow
InProcServer32\1.0.0.0\assembly - success
InProcServer32\1.0.0.0\class - success
InProcServer32\1.0.0.0\RuntimeVersion - success
InProcServer32\CodeBase - success (returns the file path)

It then checks the GAC cache, then a few directories before accessing the DLL.

CLIENT.EXE  1092    RegQueryKey HKCR\CLSID{...}    SUCCESS Query: Name
CLIENT.EXE  1092    RegOpenKey  HKCR\CLSID{...}\InprocHandler  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
CLIENT.EXE  1092    RegCloseKey HKCR\CLSID{9935FEE6-39FD-4EF0-87DB-8372B0992610}   SUCCESS 
CLIENT.EXE  1092    RegOpenKey  HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\App Management NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Query Value
CLIENT.EXE  1092    CreateFile  LogFile.txt

I think it as the last log message that the error is logged.

EDIT2: 
Dll is registered using the following code:

```
            Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(dll_name);
            RegistrationServices regAsm = new RegistrationServices();
            bool bResult = regAsm.RegisterAssembly(asm,   AssemblyRegistrationFlags.SetCodeBase);
```

EDIT3:
Running CorFlags.exe on (my) failing DLL outputs:

```
 Version   : v2.0.50727
 CLR Header: 2.5
 PE        : PE32
 CorFlags  : 11
 ILONLY    : 1
 32BIT     : 1
 Signed    : 1
```

Running the same on the EXE calling the DLL outputs:

```
 Version   : v1.1.4322
 CLR Header: 2.0
 PE        : PE32
 CorFlags  : 9
 ILONLY    : 1
 32BIT     : 0
 Signed    : 1
```

Comment: If this fails it's because it's missing a registration it needs. There are various causes to this: x86 vs x64 (seesms out here), and also security (registry permission, UAC activated, etc.). I suggest you use sysinternals procmon to monitor what registry keys are accessed. You should be able to spot the problem.

Comment: You should DOTRACE the classid returned by CLSIDFromProgID. Maybe not the one you think.

Comment: @manuell thanks for the suggestion- tried that but it didn't yield anything unexpected. Updated question to reflect

Comment: @SimonMourier - Yes good point on ProcMon. I've run a few analyses and updated the question with more info.

Comment: ok have you tried to register your .NET assembly with the "/codebase" switch? If it's not in the GAC, /codebase is a simple way to make sure the .NET dll can be found?

Comment: @SimonMourier Good point and updated the question. Yes I do register using the  /codebase option (it's in code) and there are two separate programs that run this code section. One words fine while the other gets the error.

Comment: Are both applications running in the same bitness (32 or 64 bit)?  Is your assembly marked as "Both" or 32/64 specific?

Comment: Correction: "Both" => "Any CPU"

Comment: Few more things to check: the .net runtime version being used (try explicitly setting it in the config), check the coinitializeEx and look for apartment model.

Comment: @acelent - I've updated the question to show the output of CorFlags.exe My dll is compiled to 'x86' theirs looks to be 'ANY' and the machine is an x86.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Running the same on the EXE...

You have a CLR version mismatch problem.  The EXE targets .NET 1.1 and will load the v1.1 version of the CLR.  That version cannot load the DLL, it targets the v2 version of the CLR, the one used in .NET 2.0 through 3.5

A workaround is to write a .config file that forces the right version of the CLR to be used.  Put it in the same directory as the .exe with the name somefile.exe.config, replace "somefile" with the name of the .exe:

```
<configuration>
   <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50757"/>
   </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yep that sense and thanks for helping out. Unfortunately the calling exe 3rd party legacy and putting that tag in the config causes it to crash. Are there any other work arounds?

Comment: Hmya, there are at least 3 that I can think of, none of which involves pushing a button to trivially your problem.  That button has been pushed for 11 years already, it surely is completely worn out.  If you want to push it yet again then you'll have to do a better than "it crashed".

Comment: yes point taken and sorry for the lack of useful infofmation - I'll have a go at debugging it. Unfortunately its a prod machine that runs kiosk software with useful things like explorer missing so its not the simple matter it should be.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - i'm marking it as correct and awarding the bounty because it did get me past the issue raised.